# Calculus, find the area between two given functions

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I wonder why my answers were wrong, I equaled the two functions and set them equal to zero. then I found the integral and substitute with the the given points.

ex:

$cosx - e^x$
integration of $cosx - e^x = sinx - e^x$

$|sin(1) - e^1 -( sin(0) - e^0 )| \approx 0.84147$

any help ?

Comment: You should note that it asks for 'exact value'

Comment: Its looking for the exact answer. Your answer is rounded.

Comment: @VarunIyer so what is the right answer ? I wrote sin(1)-e+1 but it was wrong.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt ^^

Comment: It doesn't make sense for area to be negative.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I fixed it, my final answer is in the post which was = 0.84147

Comment: $\sin(1)-e+1<0$

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt so what shall Ido ;/?

Comment: $|\sin(1)-e+1|=e-\sin(1)-1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $0\leq x \leq 1$, $\color{red}{e^x } \geq \color{blue}{\cos x}$,

[image]

so you should be integrating $$\int_0^1 (e^x - \cos x)\,dx$$

Now, keep the answer in its exact formulation (no rounding!).

Comment: My answer was e- sin(1) -1 , is that right ? because I only have one chance so I want to make sure

Comment: Your answer is correct.